# Storing Google map iframe to ASP.net MVC Application without security risks

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, iframe, xss

I have a MVC3 web application that has a place to input Google map address, But There is a security risk, say XSS.

Google map address contains **iframe** element and we can't use AntiXSS library to sanitize input. I also forced to turn off validation due to accept form data at controller action too.

**But How to Secure this part of application?**

Any idea perhaps technically will be useful. Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need Black-List for using `Iframe` due to control input.

An easy way is to get `Latitude` and `Longitude` as input variables by API. So using them like  below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    }


</script>
```

Or Using something more useful like [This resource](http://www.webestools.com/google-maps-code-generator-insert-map-on-website-javascript-free-google-map-script.html).